How can I change the borders in the app grid from black to transparent?
My platform is Ubuntu 24.04 LTS x86_64 and the GNOME version is 46.0. I would like to change the background of the applications and folders of the Applications grid from black to transparent. This is what I mean:

I managed to make some borders transparent, as shown in the below screenshot, but I can't change the remaining applications:

How can I make all borders transparent in the Applications grid?
Note: The background image of the app grid (mostly blue) is different from the wallpaper (ubuntu default wallpaper). The extension blur my shell turns the background image of the app grid into a wallpaper with the ubuntu logo.

The icons have their own background,  which are black. My opinion is to change the black to transparent.

.overview-icon, .app-folder { background-color: transparent } should work but the icons on dash also effects. This is a start for playing with CSS. https://i.sstatic.net/F0ymATNV.png

Ok, this should work. https://i.sstatic.net/eAlwZfLv.png. .overview-icon-with-label, .app-folder {     background-color: lightcoral; }

In your second image, the light transparent ones are folders, so from above code you can remove .app-folder if you dont want to touch them. Thanks.

.overview-icon, .app-folder { background-color: transparent } only change the app folder, just like the secnd picture.
.overview-icon has non effects.
I want to change the app's edge.

have you tried with .overview-icon-with-label is it still the same -> no effect?

Yes. Only .app-folder has effects.

Are you using any custom shell theme? Or is it the default one?

The theme is from ubuntu's default, which named Yaru blue

Hi, I installed Ubuntu 24.04 and applied the CSS .overview-icon-with-label, .app-folder {     background-color: lightcoral; } and it changed the color as expected. I think you might have some other customization/extensions that is not allowing it.

You can use the Blur my Shell extension.

Install the extension using either Extension Manager or from the GNOME Extensions website.

After installing it open the extension's settings.

By default the extension applies a blur effect to the overview, so we have to first create a custom pipeline to only apply transparency without any blur:

Go to the Pipelines tab → + Add pipeline.


Scroll to the bottom where you will find the new pipeline and name it "Transparent".


Click Manage effects  → + Add Effect  → Native gaussian blur  → click the arrow on the right and set Radius to 0.




Now go to the Overview tab and make sure that Background blur is enabled. In the Pipeline dropdown select Transparent (the one we just created). Also set Overview components style to Transparent.

Enable Application folder blur and set Application folder dialog style to Transparent.


The final result should be something like this (looks bad in my case due to the wallpaper I'm using):


This extension does not meet my needs. It's worth noting that my app grid has its own background image, and this background image is mostly blue, unlike my wallpaper. You can see this in both images.

This is information that should have been included in the question. Along with any related custom-made setting you have.
